# What does the "X_OS_IND" column mean?

Tags: r, file-formats

I want to survival analysis using the subset of TCGA LUAD dataset, which identifier are located [here](https://xenabrowser.net/datapages/?host=https%3A%2F%2Ftcga.xenahubs.net&dataset=TCGA.LUAD.sampleMap%2FLUAD_clinicalMatrix&label=Phenotypes&allIdentifiers=true).

```
> head(LUAD_clinicalMatrix[,c("X_EVENT","X_OS_IND")])
  X_EVENT X_OS_IND
1      NA       NA
2       0        0
3       1        1
4       0        0
5       0        0
6       0        0

> all(LUAD_clinicalMatrix$X_EVENT==LUAD_clinicalMatrix$X_OS_UNIT)
[1] FALSE
```

I want to know which identifier means the sample is alive or dead, and "1" means alive or dead?

Comment: Cross-posted [on biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/263414/)

Answer (score 5):

According to [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ucsc-cancer-genomics-browser/YvKnWZSsw1Q), 1=death 0=censor and null=no data.